# Edit search bar layout magento2

Tags: magento, magento2

Hi I'm new to magento!

I want to edit the layout of the search field like change its placeholder, text instead of icon for the search button, etc.

and it seems like its located here:

`/www/cleanz-aire/vendor/magento/module-search/view/frontend/templates/form.mini.phtmlMagento\Framework\View\Element\Template`

I'm working in a child theme so is there any way I can edit it from child theme?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can.

Create a directory `Magento_Search` in your theme.
`app/code/design/frontend/<vendor>/<name>/Magento_Search`

Create a file in the `Magento_Search` directory.
`app/code/design/frontend/<vendor>/<name>/Magento_Search/templates/form.mini.phtml`

Copy code from the original file (`vendor/magento/module-search/view/frontend/templates/form.mini.phtml`) into the new one and make your changes.
Don't forget to flush your caches.